postgres regexp pattern unexpected results
Using in Postgres the code
select regexp_matches('02417 02444 02442 ','^(\d{5})\s{1,}(:?(\d{5})\s{1,})*','g');

yields
{'02417','02442 ','02442'}
while I was expecting
{'02417','02444','02442'}

What should I do to get the expected result ?
( obviously my case is much more complicated and I reduced it to a simple example. This is to say that a trivial answer just tailored the the exact case above is not pertinent, the answer should address how to get all matches in any case ).

Do you want an array of text as the result or a single plain text value of {'02417','02444','02442'} that looks like an array literal? btw, your code does not yield {'02417','02442 ','02442'} as you have posted, but instead yields {02417,"02442 ",02442}. See demo. Have you posted the right code?

Please define the task in plain English. What is the intention of your regexp? Tell us your Postgres version, the data type of the input and the desired output data type.

"This is to say that a trivial answer just tailored the the exact case above is not pertinent, the answer should address how to get all matches in any case". But how are we supposed to know what "any case" looks like? You haven't explained what exactly you are trying to match and in what form the input string might be other than what you have supplied.

You can't get all the captures of any capturing group ("repeated capturing group") with PostgreSQL regex. Simply not supported. BUT as a workaround, you can assume you have X amount of such groups and then use X amount of optional non-capturing groups in your pattern, see this answer. So, if you can have up to 5 - ^(\d{5})(?:\s+(\d{5}))?(?:\s+(\d{5}))?(?:\s+(\d{5}))?(?:\s+(\d{5}))?(?:\s+(\d{5}))?

@WiktorStribiżew - that's horrible! :-) You've answered a couple of my questions in the past - once to explain why it couldn't be done in PostgreSQL (something about capturing groups in lookbehinds not being supported. Not there yet, but I did the following workaround - why don't i get (using '\d+')
1, {02417,02444,02442}
2, {02417,02444,02444,02442}
immediately? (Last snippet). Any clue?

Not sure what the problem is here. \d+ matches all sequences of 1 or more digits.

@WiktorStribiżew BTW, there is this - why it can't be core, I don't know. The guy is a major contributor!

@WiktorStribiżew - exactly, hence my confusion! Thanks anyway - I'll ask on the lists!

You could try (fiddle here):
SELECT
  REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(TRIM('02417    02444 02442  '), '\s+');

Result (both results are the same - this is probably the betterp solution):
regexp_split_to_array
{02417,02444,02442}

Or
SELECT
  STRING_TO_ARRAY(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM('02417    02444 02442   '), '\s+', ' ', 'g'), ' ');

See here for a more detailed treatment which I worked on not knowing the question had been closed. Don't understand why I get separate single element arrays (with either '\d+' - all digits or with '[^ ]' - anything but a space) instead of a 3 (record 1) or 4 element array?
